# running pig script with udf on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop-streaming

I m new to hadoop and pig. I wonder how to run a pig script that internally calls a UDF method? The thing is I dont see the statement "register blah.jar" mentioned like on Pig UDF Manual site:

```
register myudfs.jar;
A = load 'student_data' as (name: chararray, age: int, gpa: float);
B = foreach A generate flatten(myudfs.Swap(name, age)), gpa;
C = foreach B generate $2;
D = limit B 20;
dump D;
```

But i do see a "jar" directory that contains "blah.jar". My coworker left already, so i wonder what was the trick? Maybe I can add the jar file to the command line?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried running the script? If so, do you get an error message?  What is the name of the UDF being called?

Comment: If you could answer @WinnieNicklaus's questions, that would help us understand what the problem may be.  Too many questions at this point.

Comment: Winnie and Dan, I have not tried to run the script. Since I actually have two questions (or more). first of all, I am not sure how exactly I can generate a myudfs.jar. So on my mac, should I just open a project on eclipse and add pig's lib/jar, then code the UDF and wrap everything into myudfs.jar? Secondly, in the script, do i really need "register myudfs.jar"? If not, how does pig find the jar?

Comment: What is the name of the UDF?

Comment: Winnie, I wanna code the UDF you suggested in another question thread of mine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no `REGISTER` statement in the script (and the script is valid), then it does not call any UDFs except possibly any of Pig's [builtin functions](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/udf_lists.html).  If you would like to use a UDF, you will need a `REGISTER` statement.  `REGISTER` is unnecessary if no UDFs are called, which is probably why you don't see it in the script you have.

[Here](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/writing_udfs.html) is a good reference on writing UDFs.  After you have written it, you will need to compile it into a jar file, being sure to also include any classes it depends on (such as EvalFunc).  This is the jar you will `REGISTER`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Winnie! I am now surprised with the script i read at work that calls some UDFs but no register on the top of the script...But at least i can firstly build my own UDF to understand how to run it in the script, then i will find out more :) Really appreciate your help! :)